# CloudDeploy neural network unknown error

Tags: neural-networks, wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I tried to use CloudDeploy to put my nicely trained network into the cloud for other people to use. However, after calling the following:

```
CloudDeploy[FormPage[{"image"->"Image"},Net[#image]&],Permissions->"Public"]
```

I get an unknown error. Is there a way to deploy neural networks into the cloud at this moment?

The trained net can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/if91qh5ue1v6cj4/TestNet.wlnet?dl=0

Best,
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible issues:

1. You could be hitting a time-out
2. The definitions aren't exported properly

Try this:

```
netco = CloudExport[net, "MX", Permissions -> "Public"];

form =
  FormPage[{"img" -> "Image"},
   With[{result = CloudImport[netco][#img]},
     Grid[{
       Keys[result],
       Values[result]
       }]
     ] &
   ];

co = CloudDeploy[form, "net_form", Permissions -> "Public"];
```

That will solve problem 2 and is generally fast-enough for me. Here's a sample resulting image:

[image: test]

I'll leave that one live [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/net_form) until you can confirm it works. Beware that it crushes your cloud credits. Each call takes 30-50 cloud credits for me.

If it's a time-out issue, you may need to use smaller images or a paid account.

Comment: I can confirm that your solution works.

Comment: 30-50 seconds is crazy slow

Comment: @M.R. It's cloud credits not seconds

Comment: Oh nice, we'll I'd like to hear how it works for you in terms of time, throughput and cost - the Wolfram Cloud doesn't have gpus, and when I tried a few months back, calling a net on many or large images crashed the process very quickly.

Comment: @M.R. I put that thing back up. Feel free to try it for yourself. In general a computation aborts if it takes more than like 5 seconds I think, so it's taking less than that. I sent in a 741kb GIF of `{320, 239}` pixels to get that mess up there.

Comment: @b3m2a1 How would it work as an APIFunction, that is, how would I encode the image into a query url? I'm in javascript right now and I'd like to call an image processing api...

Answer (score 1):

Nontrivial convolutional neural networks do not work in the cloud, even if you have the top-tier subscription. I tried really hard to get this to work. The cloud is too flaky and not ready for prime times.